# myBatis uses only a few connection from its BasicDataSource pool

Tags: connection-pooling, mybatis

I have been using myBatis with org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource as the data source.
for some reason, even under an impossible load, myBatis uses only a few connections from the pool (around 23).
As you can see below my initial size of connections is 50, but some of them just stay idle.
Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="#{'jdbc:mysql://' + mysql + ':3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true'}"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="50"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="50"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="1000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatisConfiguration.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: How do you check that connections are idle? Are you sure that there is no other bottleneck up the stack like number of threads in in a pool of http request processor in servlet container (for tomcat this is maxThreads in Executor)?

Comment: I am looking at mySql "show processlist" and see that many connections are not utilized. when I replace the insert line of myBatis (interface.someInsert) with a regular get connections (from the pool), I see that all the connections are utilized, so I assume the issue is with how myBatis uses the pool.

Comment: When you say "all connections are utilized" , did you notice whether these connections get freed away after the use ? I am just suspecting if there is any resource leak in your non mybatis implementation of your code !!